# How to add quote marks to text in HAML code

Tags: haml, double-quotes

I have the following HAML code

```
//add some text
%div.text
  <%= answer.text %>
```

The result in the browser is as such

[image]

How can I add quote marks to this text so that is shows "test remuse" instead?

Comment: Using `<%= "#{answer.text}" %>` may work.

Comment: How are you running this? `<%= .. %>` is erb, not Haml. It looks like you’re mixing up Haml and erb.

Answer (score 0):

A more natural solution:

```
//add some text
%div.text
  "#{answer.text}"
```

And I think you don't need a `%div`, because `.text` is a `div` with `class="text"`:

```
.text
  "#{answer.text}"
```